# value and matche in rows

Tags: excel, vlookup

I need a specific VLOOKUP formula to return all values and multiple matches in rows. An example of input and output tables is below. It seems to me that generic VLOOKUP function in Excel does not help with multiple matches.

[image]

Comment: A formula is not the way to go here.  VBA will be needed.

Comment: Why is `Adam radio Steve` not a row in the results table? You need to clearly lay out your logic behind the before/after.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a small example of how this could be accomplished via VBA, note that this is NOT a dynamic solution for any setup - you also haven't provided details on that, or how you're getting your results. You'll notice my output is different from yours:

Typically I don't answer questions where an attempt hasn't been shown, but when @ScottCraner can't solve via a formula I have to tout my VBA :)

```
Option Explicit
Sub PopulateTable()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long

    k = 16
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        For j = 2 To lastrow2
            If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 5).Value Then
                Cells(k, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
                Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
                Cells(k, 3).Value = Cells(j, 4).Value
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: BTW, I did not say I could not do this with a formula.  I said it shouldn't be done with a formula.  I could do this with formulas.  The issue is the formula would be array formula and as such if the data set is large it would be problematic.

Comment: Thanks dwirony for the prompt response with VBA! Let me try it on a big worksheet with several thousand values.

Comment: And ^^^^^^^^That is why I suggested VBA. I would make one suggestion to speed it up, use variant arrays instead of looping the ranges.

Comment: @ScottCraner Haha I was just messing around,  I'm certain you could've done it, yes :)